# How to Insert & Update Multiple Record in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views, django-mysql

I want to know how to deal with this task.
here are the details:
this is product_feature model

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    has_value_choice = [
        ('y', 'Yes'),
        ('n', 'No'),
    ]
    feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    feature_has_value = models.CharField(choices=has_value_choice, max_length = 1, null = False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Product_feature(models.Model):
    product_feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_feature_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

here, I'm passing features data to the template to save features of the specific product in the product_feature model.

```
                  <form>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Features</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for data in features_data %}
                                    <tr>
                                        {% if data.feature_has_value != 'n' %}
                                            <td>{{ data.feature_name }}</td>
                                            <td><input type="text" name="{{ data.feature_name }}" id="{{ data.feature_name }}" placeholder="Enter {{ data.feature_name }}" class="form-control" required/></td>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <td>{{ data.feature_name }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <select id="{{ data.feature_name }}" name="{{ data.feature_name }}" class="form-control" required>
                                                    <option selected id="select" value="yes">Yes</option>
                                                    <option value="no">No</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </tr>        
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                       </form>
```

Now, the thing is how to insert this form data to the product features table( product_feature model at the starting of the question).

I want to insert multiple records in the product features a table with each record have it's feature_id, product_id & product_feature value.

I'm really confused about how to do this I'm new in Django development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a django admin which defaults adds to your url
In admin.py register models , you can use default ui

```
from django.contrib import admin

 # Register your models here.
 from medicine.models import Address,Shop


 class ShopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('name', 'phone', 'address')


 class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('line_1', 'line_2', 'city', 'state', 'lat', 'lng')






 admin.site.register(Shop, ShopAdmin)
 admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
```

./manage.py make migrations
./manage.py createsuperuser
and your app in insatlled apps

For cutsomized ui you need to have a another form that takes data and give it to backed using a request.body as json

The best practice is using django rest framework where you can define your end points and use seriizarers which gives the way to communicate in json/xml any  supportable format

For inserting of data take everything as query param or payload body

For just creating objects to your model use this

```
obj = MyModel.objects.create(value)
```

Comment: No! but I'm not using the Django default admin panel I have created my customized admin panel is there a solution to my question?

Comment: yes,  you can read the value submitted to backend as dictionary and create object to your model

Comment: Please give any link if there is?

Comment: you need to have views fetch and validate your form and save!  please mark this as  answer, if it answers your question

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a `ModelFormSet` of feature forms. This allows you to duplicate one form for multiple objects. The documentation is a good on-ramp: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: thanks for this but you can check my question I work with normal or custom form not working with Django form so as per you there is another solution?

Comment: You can still use custom HTML with a Django Form or FormSet class used server side. This is covered in the Form documentaion here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually